# Set alignment on the bases of string value

Tags: c#, wpf, parsing, enums

i am trying this but not sure what it needs as parameter.

```
VerticalAlignment.TryParse("top"); // Must return VerticalAlignment.Top & ignore case
```

Is there any way to achieve this? please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`VerticalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.verticalalignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an enum, so try using [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
var result = (VerticalAlignment)Enum.Parse(typeof(VerticalAlignment), "top", true);
```

Of course, you can also write your own generic method to make this syntax more palatable:

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>(string stringValue) where T : struct
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), stringValue, true);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var result = ParseEnum<VerticalAlignment>("top");
```

Comment: Awesome, sweet looking. worked great. thanks for prompt response

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an enum use this

```
VerticAligment va = (VerticalAlignment)Enum.Parse(typeof(VerticalAlignment), "top", true);
```

The last value is the ignoreCase property you need to make it match case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it - you just have to specify the second parameter as `true` to ignore case:

```
VerticalAlignment alignment;
VerticalAlignment.TryParse("Top", true, out alignment);
```

Comment: +1 thanks, is there anyway i can do like this without declaring alignment seperately: VerticalAlignment.TryParse("Top", true, out VerticalAlignment alignment); I have to do this for many types, and declaring each variable doest taste good to me.

Comment: Thanks, i'll use that in future